# How to override keybindings from a parent scheme in Eclipse 4?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am upgrading an RCP application to use Eclipse 4.2.1. One of the problems I am having is that keybindings in my custom scheme are no longer overriding Eclipse key bindings.

I have reproduced the problem in a sample plug-in project. This was created by following, then adapting, [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html). I can't attach the project itself, so have just included the contents of the plugin.xml file.

I have my own scheme which extends the default scheme:

```
  <scheme
        id="test.MyScheme"
        name="My Scheme"
        parentId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
  </scheme>
```

I have a command with the key binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>:

```
  <key
        commandId="test.MyCommand"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        schemeId="test.MyScheme"
        sequence="M1+N">
  </key>
```

In Eclipse 3.7.2, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> would run my command.

In Eclipse 4.2.1, it pops up a box asking me to choose between running my command and launching the 'New' wizard. What do I need to do to restore the original behaviour?

Full contents of plugin.xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="test.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            name="RCP Perspective"
            class="test.Perspective"
            id="test.perspective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="test.MyCommandHandler"
            id="test.MyCommand"
            name="My Command">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="fileMenu"
               label="File">
            <command
                  commandId="test.MyCommand"
                  label="My Command"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="test.MyCommand"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            schemeId="test.MyScheme"
            sequence="M1+N">
      </key>
      <scheme
            id="test.MyScheme"
            name="My Scheme"
            parentId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
      </scheme>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="test.application"
            name="My Product">
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="My Product">
         </property>
         <property
               name="preferenceCustomization"
               value="plugin_customization.ini">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The old mechanism appears to just not work but there is another way.

1. Add an extension org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model
2. Add a processor fragment
3. Find the offending key binding: MAppliction->MBindingTable->MKeyBinding
4. Remove the key binding from the binding table

Answer (score 0):

The following file might be missing inside your plugin directory next to the plugin.xml:

```
plugin_customization.ini
```

Its content should be:

```
org.eclipse.ui/KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID=test.MyScheme
```

See also, this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html) and the [chapter here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#keybindings).